# How to call suspend function from Service Android?

Tags: kotlin, android-service, kotlin-coroutines, coroutine

How to provide scope or how to call suspend function from Service Android?
Usually, activity or viewmodel provides us the scope, from where we can launch suspend but there is no similar thing in Service

Answer (score 79, accepted):

You can create your own [`CoroutineScope`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-coroutine-scope/index.html) with a [`SupervisorJob`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-supervisor-job.html) that you can cancel in the `onDestroy()` method. The coroutines created with this scope will live as long as your Service is being used. Once `onDestroy()` of your service is called, all coroutines started with this scope will be cancelled.

```
class YourService : Service() {

    private val job = SupervisorJob()
    private val scope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO + job)

    ...

    fun foo() {
        scope.launch {
            // Call your suspend function
        }
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        job.cancel()
    }
}
```

Edit: Changed `Dispatchers.Main` to `Dispatchers.IO`

Comment: Why would you use Dispatchers.main in a scope for a Service? Wouldn't you use Dispatchers.IO instead?

Comment: Main Disoatcher is completely fine and I would argue is better solution! Service is also running on the main thread by default, so this scope keep semantics of the service. You always can wrap with IO/'Default dispatcher for any heavy operations specifically

Comment: It is best to replace `job.cancel()` by `job.cancelChildren()` at `onDestroy` because if your service is shown multiple time only the first coroutine will work.

Answer (score 6):

for me worked like that

```
import androidx.lifecycle.lifecycleScope
class ServiceLife : LifecycleService() {
    private var supervisorJob = SupervisorJob(parent = null)
    override fun onCreate()  {
        super.onCreate()
        val serviceJob = lifecycleScope.launch {
            //some suspend fun
        }
          supervisorJob[serviceJob.key]
          supervisorJob.cancel()
    }
}
```

Comment: I think your answer is the correct one, to use LifecycleService, but you don't need serviceJob or SupervisorJob here, it looks really unnecessary for this answer, so lifecycleScope is enough

Answer (score 5):

[**`SupervisorJob()`**](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-supervisor-job.html) (Kotlin GitHub) is a job that provides **uniderectional cancellation**; it allows for cancellations to propogate *downwards only*.

> The SupervisorJob ... is similar to a regular Job with the only exception that cancellation is propagated only downwards. [[KotlinLang.org](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/exception-handling.html#supervision-job)]

**Use case**:  You have a service that makes a log entry, checks settings, and depending on those settings goes ahead and performs some actions. Do you want all children jobs of the parent job (scope) to cancel if, for instance, a job run based on settings' values throws an exception?  If not (i.e. you still want your logging and check for settings jobs to complete at the least) then you want to use the `SupervisorJob()`, or even [`supervisorScope`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/supervisor-scope.html) *(Kotlin GitHub)* for '*scoped* concurrency' [[KotlinLang.org](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/exception-handling.html#supervision-scope)], as both provide unidirectional job cancellation - and in that case the provided answer works.

[Coroutine Exception Handling - Supervision](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/exception-handling.html#supervision) (KotlinLang.org)

However, there is a more direct solution that answers the question.

To provide to your service a scope with which to run coroutines (or suspending functions) that execute blocking code, you can simply create a new [**`CoroutineScope()`**](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-coroutine-scope/index.html) with an [**`EmptyCoroutineContext`**](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.coroutines/-empty-coroutine-context/):

(Snippet from CoroutineScope Documentation)

> If the given [context](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-coroutine-scope.html) does not contain a Job element, then a default [`Job()`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-job/index.html) is created. This way, [cancellation](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/cancel.html) or failure of any child coroutine in this scope cancels all the other children, just like inside [coroutineScope](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/coroutine-scope.html) block [[Kotlin GitHub](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-coroutine-scope.html)]

```kotlin
class YourClass : Extended() {
    ...

    private val serviceScope: CoroutineScope( EmptyCoroutineContext )

    ...

    private inner class ServiceHandler( looper: Looper ): Handler( looper ) {
        override fun handleMessage( msg: Message ) {
            super.handleMessage( msg )

            serviceScope.launch {
               try{
+              ...
               } catch( e: Exception ) {
+              ...
               } finally {
                   stopSelf( msg.arg1 )
               }
            }
        }
    }


    override fun onCreate(){
+   ...
    }

    override fun onDestroy(){
        /* In a service, unlike in an activity, we do not
           need to make a call to the super implementation */
        //super.onDestory()
        serviceScope.cancel()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can extend `LifecycleService` rather than `Service` on your class. This will provide you access to `lifecycleScope` in your service, just like in an Activity or Fragment.